# Среда разработки IDEA конфликтует с PHPStorm, как решить?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Есть среда разработки для `Java` **IntelliJ IDEA**, так вот, когда параллельно открываешь **PhpStorm** в нем почему-то открывается проект на `Java`, и он соответственно стирает/устанавливает свои настройки и прочие, из-за чего возникают сложности.
Подскажите как решить данную проблемы.

Win10x64.
Домашние директории:

> `c:\Users\xxx\`
>   .IntelliJIdea2018.3
>   .PhpStorm2018.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm и IDEA используют один и тот же формат проектных файлов, но настройки, типы поддерживаемых модулей и проч. у них разные. Поэтому, если хочется работать с одним и тем же проектом одновременно в 2 средах, рекомендуется иметь разные папки `.idea`. Например, можно создать новый пустой проект в PhpStorm и потом добавить к нему папку с web файлами из вашего IDEA проекта в качестве дополнительного content root (**Settings | Directories, Add content root**)

Comment: тут такое дело, я не работаю в двух средах над одним проектом. Работаю в одной среде, запускаю паралейно другую среду, а она почему-то открывает проект первого. в частности PHPStorm открывает проект IDEA

Comment: значит, вы один раз его там открывали, и она просто переоткрывает его на старте (по умолчанию всегда открывается последний открытый проект). Просто закройте проект перез закрытием среды, и она будет стартовать без открытия проектов

Comment: Возможно вы правы, вроде такого больше не повторяется. Спасибо!